# Getting Product Price Null At Observer

Tags: event-observer

I have a problem with my observer. I want to apply a discount on the before product add to cart event, but I am getting all price set as null. My observer code is:

```
public function applyCartDiscount(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $item = $item->getParentItem();
    }

    // Discounted 25% off
    $percentDiscount = 0.25;

    // This makes sure the discount isn't applied over and over when refreshing
    $specialPrice = $item->getOriginalPrice() - ($item->getOriginalPrice() * $percentDiscount);

    // Make sure we don't have a negative
    $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

}
```

When I print array using

```
print_r($item->toArray());
```

It gives array something like

```
Array
(
    [item_id] => 21
    [quote_id] => 4
    [created_at] => 2013-11-28 05:46:02
    [updated_at] => 2013-11-28 05:46:02
    [product_id] => 51
    [store_id] => 1
    [parent_item_id] => 
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [sku] => 1111
    [name] => Ottoman
    [description] => 
    [applied_rule_ids] => 
    [additional_data] => 
    [free_shipping] => 0
    [is_qty_decimal] => 0
    [no_discount] => 0
    [weight] => 20.0000
    [qty] => 2
    [price] => 0.0000
    [base_price] => 0.0000
    [custom_price] => 0.0000
    [discount_percent] => 0.0000
    [discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [tax_percent] => 0.0000
    [tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [row_total] => 0.0000
    [base_row_total] => 0.0000
    [row_total_with_discount] => 0.0000
    [row_weight] => 20.0000
    [product_type] => simple
    [base_tax_before_discount] => 
    [tax_before_discount] => 
    [original_custom_price] => 0.0000
    [gift_message_id] => 
    [weee_tax_applied] => a:0:{}
    [weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0.0000
    [weee_tax_applied_row_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_weee_tax_applied_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_weee_tax_applied_row_amnt] => 
    [weee_tax_disposition] => 0.0000
    [weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0.0000
    [base_weee_tax_disposition] => 0.0000
    [base_weee_tax_row_disposition] => 0.0000
    [redirect_url] => 
    [base_cost] => 50.0000
    [price_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [base_price_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [row_total_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [base_row_total_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [hidden_tax_amount] => 
    [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 
    [qty_options] => Array
        (
        )
[product] => Array
    (
        [store_id] => 1
        [entity_id] => 51
        [entity_type_id] => 10
        [attribute_set_id] => 42
        [type_id] => simple
        [sku] => 1111
        [created_at] => 2007-08-28 16:25:46
        [updated_at] => 2008-08-08 14:59:04
        [has_options] => 0
        [required_options] => 0
        [name] => Ottoman
        [meta_title] => Ottoman
        [meta_description] => Ottoman
        [image] => /o/t/ottoman.jpg
        [small_image] => /o/t/ottoman.jpg
        [url_key] => ottoman
        [thumbnail] => /o/t/ottoman.jpg
        [gift_message_available] => 
        [url_path] => ottoman.html
        [custom_design] => 
        [options_container] => container2
        [color] => 26
        [status] => 1
        [tax_class_id] => 2
        [room] => 72
        [visibility] => 4
        [description] => The Magento ottoman will impress with its style while it delivers on quality. This piece of living room furniture is built to last with durable solid wood framing, generous padding and plush stain-resistant microfiber upholstery.
        [meta_keyword] => Ottoman
        [dimension] => 
        [model] => magotto
        [short_description] => With durable solid wood framing, generous padding and plush stain-resistant microfiber upholstery.
        [country_orgin] => Italy
        [finish] => Microfiber
        [custom_layout_update] => 
        [price] => 299.9900
        [cost] => 50.0000
        [weight] => 20.0000
        [minimal_price] => 299.9900
        [group_price] => Array
            (
            )

        [group_price_changed] => 0
        [tier_price] => Array
            (
            )

        [tier_price_changed] => 0
        [media_gallery] => Array
            (
                [images] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [value_id] => 201
                                [file] => /o/t/ottoman.jpg
                                [label] => 
                                [position] => 0
                                [disabled] => 1
                                [label_default] => 
                                [position_default] => 0
                                [disabled_default] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [values] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [stock_item] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 29
                [product_id] => 51
                [stock_id] => 1
                [qty] => 706.0000
                [min_qty] => 0.0000
                [use_config_min_qty] => 1
                [is_qty_decimal] => 0
                [backorders] => 0
                [use_config_backorders] => 1
                [min_sale_qty] => 1.0000
                [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1
                [max_sale_qty] => 100.0000
                [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1
                [is_in_stock] => 1
                [low_stock_date] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [notify_stock_qty] => 
                [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1
                [manage_stock] => 0
                [use_config_manage_stock] => 1
                [stock_status_changed_auto] => 0
                [use_config_qty_increments] => 1
                [qty_increments] => 0.0000
                [use_config_enable_qty_inc] => 1
                [enable_qty_increments] => 0
                [is_decimal_divided] => 0
                [type_id] => simple
                [stock_status_changed_automatically] => 0
                [use_config_enable_qty_increments] => 1
                [product_name] => Ottoman
                [store_id] => 1
                [product_type_id] => simple
                [product_status_changed] => 1
                [product_changed_websites] => 
                [ordered_items] => 2
            )

        [is_in_stock] => 1
        [is_salable] => 1
        [website_ids] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [cart_qty] => 1
        [qty] => 1
        [stick_within_parent] => 
        [customer_group_id] => 0
        [final_price] => 
    )

[tax_class_id] => 2
[is_recurring] => 
[has_error] => 
[qty_to_add] => 1
```

Please help where am I going wrong..

Comment: Is there any reason to change code to add discount? You can do this using Catalog Price Rule also. For more detail please review http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-catalog-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them

Comment: yes discount is dynamic come from one of my api for perticuler customer group

Comment: @what event are you observing?

Comment: checkout_cart_product_add_after

Comment: you can get added product price by using  
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$price = $product->getPrice();

Answer (score 3):

The problem happens because the attribute `original_price` is only set after the totals have been collected. It is set in `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Subtotal` as part of the function `_recollectItem`.

The reason that you get 0 for price is because the first time you add to the cart you are resetting the prices to 0.